# É necessário especificar o MIME type na propriedade src ao renderizar uma imagem em base64?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Estou fazendo alguns testes de renderização de imagem em **base64** e me surgiu algumas dúvidas.

Percebi que mesmo passando a extensão da imagem errada no **mime type**, ainda é possível renderizar a imagem, no exemplo abaixo, uma imagem que tinha extensão `.PNG`, ao especificar 
 a extensão como `data:image/jpeg`, ela ainda assim é renderizada. No segundo exemplo foi retirado a especificação da extensão e a imagem também é renderizada:

```js
document.getElementById('imageBase64Png').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

document.getElementById('imageBase64WithoutType').src = ' data:image;base64, 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'
```

```html
Imagem em base 64 com formato png utilizando mimetype image/jpeg:
<img id="imageBase64Png" />
<br>
Imagem em base64 com formato png sem especificar tipo:
<img id="imageBase64WithoutType" />
```

Há alguma vantagem ou desvantagem de especificar ou não a extensão da imagem no MIME type visto que mesmo passando uma extensão que não é a correta, o navegador consegue interpretar e renderizar?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types e atenção na parte que fala sobre **MIME sniffing**

Comment: @hugocsl muito obrigado, este link tirou muito das minhas dúvidas :)

Answer (score -1):

O mimetype é divido em tipo/subtipo
Nos 2 casos vc especificou um mimetype do tipo imagem, com a diferença em que no primeiro exemplo vc especificou o subtipo "jpeg"

Vc pode ver mais a fundo aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types